# Java - method parameters, String followed by List

Tags: java, list, arraylist, parameter-passing, method-parameters

I have a Java method that accepts a `String` and an `String<List>` as method parameters. How do I differentiate the String from not being part of the List?

Method:

```
void returnValues(String sensor, List<String> attributes)
```

Call:

```
nexaConnect.returnValues(Arrays.asList("19455746", "blobJson", "deviceMfg", "eventCode", "sensorClass", "sensorUUID", "timeStamp", "uID"));
```

The only possible work around I can see is to remove the first String and include the value within the List and then get the first value of the list and use it that way. Is there any way to separate them out so that it's not part of the list?

Comment: i don´t really get what you want, but `returnValues("This is not Part of the List", yourList);` should be enough?

Comment: Where is the first argument?

Comment: _I have a JAVA method that accepts a String and an List<String>_ well first, you should pass those argument when you call this method. Then, you should show your logic to search if it is contained in the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The attempt to call `returnValues` does not match the formal parameters. Assuming that's what you're asking, then like this.

```
nexaConnect.returnValues("TheFirst", Arrays.asList("19455746", "blobJson", 
    "deviceMfg", "eventCode", "sensorClass", 
    "sensorUUID", "timeStamp", "uID"));
```

**or** save the references to local variables and it looks like,

```
String sensor = "TheFirst";
List<String> attributes = Arrays.asList("19455746", "blobJson", 
    "deviceMfg", "eventCode", "sensorClass", 
    "sensorUUID", "timeStamp", "uID");
nexaConnect.returnValues(sensor, attributes);
```

Comment: just going to note that using varargs as `String... listItems` would be an other option, considering the `List` only gets initialized for the methodcall, if it´s not a simple example call and it doesn´t need to modify a potentionally passed `List` reference. This way the `Array.asList` call could be removed.

Comment: How do I differentiate the String from not being part of the List? I think this is the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

For now, you have a method signature

```
void methodName(String arg1, List<String> arg2)
```

that you are call using a signature similar to

```
void methodName(List<String> arg2)
```

You need to match the signature when you call a method, so pass a String has first argument then the list.

So instead of calling it like

```
instance.methodName(anInstanceOfList);
```

First pass a String value

```
instance.methodName(aStringValue, anInstanceOfList);
```